# Makefiles - Compiling to a different target folder

Tags: build, makefile

I have a list of library folders that I'm specifying in a make file:

```
LIBRARIES = Ethernet                \
            SPI                     \
            SD
```

I also have a number of rules for compiling each one into a local obj folder of my project:

```
obj/SPI/%.cpp.o: $(LIBS_DIR)/SPI/%.cpp
    @echo "Compiling $<"

obj/SD/%.cpp.o: $(LIBS_DIR)/SD/%.cpp
    @echo "Compiling $<"    

obj/Ethernet/%.cpp.o: $(LIBS_DIR)/Ethernet/%.cpp
    @echo "Compiling $<"
```

(Note that each one uses it's own sub-folder). How can I generate these rules from $(LIBRARIES) automatically so that I don't have to duplicate them like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
obj/%.cpp.o : $(LIBS_DIR)/%.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} $<
```

In the above `%` captures `dir/src` part.

If you'd like the output directories to be created automatically it can be done with [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) make feature:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

obj/%.cpp.o : $(LIBS_DIR)/%.cpp | $${@D} # object file depends on its directory
    g++ -c -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} $<

obj/% : # directory creation rule
    mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim, secondary expansion is what I wound up using in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Sufficiently new versions of GNU make support the eval function.  You can use it like this:

```
define SUBDIR_RULE
obj/$1/%.cpp.o: $(LIBS_DIR)/$1/%.cpp
        @echo "Compiling $$<"
enddef

$(foreach D,$(LIBRARIES),$(eval $(call SUBDIR_RULE,$D)))
```

If you don't want to rely on that you can use auto-generated makefiles, which have been a feature of GNU make for much much longer.  But this method is slightly trickier to use.